# How to add 1 hour to record created date to run a Apex scheduler?

Tags: apex, community, scheduled-apex

Hello All i am trying to run an Apex scheduler which i need to fire once if the DML fails in catch block. How to add 1 hour from the datetime where the exception is caught on the fly?

```
    catch(exception ex)
    {
        system.debug(ex.getmessage());
        Exception_Log__c E = new Exception_Log__c();
        e.name = QuoteID ;
        e.Exception_Body__c = 'File Name:'+cv.title+' '+ex.getmessage() + 'This might be due to 
        Incorrect File name or No Parent id is found for the file';
        e.ContentDocumentID__c = cv.contentdocumentid;
        e.ContentTitle__c = cv.title;
        insert e;
        system.debug('++Ex'+e);
        datetime currenttime = datetime.now();
        datetime addedhour = currenttime.addhours(1); 
        system.debug('+++Added hour+++'+addedhour);
        BatchScheduleUpdate bs = new BatchScheduleUpdate ();
        String sch = '0 0 8 13 2 ?';  // Need help here
        system.schedule('One Time Pro1', sch, bs);
        }
```

Comment: Is BatchScheduleUpdate a Batchable as well as Schedulable? If so you could use System.scheduleBatch which uses a time interval instead of cron string for scheduling relative to now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the cron like this:

```
Datetime workTime = System.now().addHours(1);
String CRONEXP = '' + workTime.second() + ' ' + workTime.minute() + ' ' + workTime.hour()
    + ' ' + workTime.day() + ' ' + workTime.month() + ' ? ' + workTime.year();
System.schedule('One Time Pro1', CRONEXP, bs);
```

Comment: One of the issues with using System.schedule is that the job name of the schedule ('One Time Pro1') cannot be re-used so you must either use a new name each time or ensure that the jobs are cleaned up when no longer required. Cleaning up is not always possible due to permissions. This is part of the reason I asked about whether it was a Batchable, since System.scheduleBatch automatically cleans up the job once complete.

Comment: Hi Maria , Thanks for the reply. you are right I am writing a delete job to cleanse these records automatically once every day.  Also system.now() pick up which time zone ?

Comment: @Nirmal Returns the current date and time in the GMT time zone.

Comment: @PhilW From the question I made a guess that this code runs from Admin. Also cleaning up the job can be easily done in scheduler from ```System.SchedulableContext sc``` as ```System.abortJob(sc.getTriggerId());```. This also help with name, because in this case scheduler name can be randomly generated.